# What is the information returned by docker inspect for .Mounts?

Tags: docker

Ie, if I do:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' base-hostSrcNv
```

I might get:

```
[{bind  /dir/in/container /dir/on/host   true }]
```

The meaning of `/dir/in/container` and `/dir/on/host` is pretty easy to understand.  But what's the last boolean value represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the **write** or **read** mode on the container. But you can enter this command for more detail in the return:

```
    docker inspect --format="{{json .Mounts}}" base-hostSrcNv
```

You can also use **jq** (***apt install jq***) tool to have beautiful json output:

```
    docker inspect --format="{{json .Mounts}}" base-hostSrcNv | jq
```